# Number of classes in Java EE framework?

Tags: java

[This page](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2008/03/17/number-of-types-in-the-net-framework.aspx) lists the number of classes, assemblies, etc. for the .NET Framework. Does a   similar list exist for the Java EE framework?

Comment: What do you need it for?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the main page which lists down all the classes in [J2EE](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/index.html). no statistics though. Even google doesnt turn up any statistics.

Comment: 740 classes and interfaces mentioned on that page ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could [go count them](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/) (programmatically, of course). Java Enterprise Edition requires Java Standard Edition, so you'd have to sum the two. Here are the results for the public API types for the JEE5 standard:

```
http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/
packages: 79
classes: 1045

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/
packages: 166
classes: 3278
```

Of course, it isn't that simple. More recent JEE5 servers will be bundled with and/or run on JSE6 and server vendors often bundle more up-to-date enterprise components and non-standard libraries for value-add. The Java ecosystem is a bit more diverse than the .Net world.

Comment: So the .NET Framework 3.5 is about twice the size in terms of number of classes/types ?